# confused about use of PHP operators

Tags: php, operators, comparison-operators

Ahoy all. I've got a contact form PHP script.  I use it for multiple sites since it's quick and easy.  Basically, it loops through ALL the form fields in a contact form, no matter what they are. Makes it so I don't have to manually do the POST thing one by one.

ANYWAY, my question is simple. Below is a snippet of the code:

```
if ($thisField != "contact-submit") {
    if (($thisField != "human2"))  {
         $msg .= "<b>".$thisField ."</b>: ". $thisValue ."<br>";
    }
    }
```

Now, the problem with it doing this loop is it picks up ALL things submitted, including the SUBMIT BUTTON and my hidden form field to deter robots. I don't want to display THOSE fields to my clients.

So instead of doing these two nested loops, I was thinking of doing a

```
if (($thisField != "human2") or ($thisField != "contact-submit")
```

but it just doesn't work...  I have also tried the || operator as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expression always evaluated to true. If you compare a value to two different values, it is always unequal to at least one of them. 
I think you meant to use `and`, or `&&`, so you can check if the value isn't any of those two values.

```
if (($thisField != "human2") && ($thisField != "contact-submit")
```

or

```
if (!($thisField === "human2" or $thisField === "contact-submit"))
```

or

```
if (($thisField === "human2" or $thisField === "contact-submit") === false)
// Because you might easily overlook the exclamation mark in the second example
```

or use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if (! in_array($thisField, array('human2', 'contact-submit')))
// Easier add extra fields. You could stick the array in a variable too, for better readability
```

Comment: You’re wrong. If `$thisField` equals `0`, both expressions are true.

Comment: Yes, so the expression as a whole still evaluates to true. My point exactly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant they are false and not true: `0 != "human2"` is false and `0 != "contact-submit"` is false as both strings are converted to integer and also yield `0`.

Comment: Alright. In theory that is true, but in the context of the question, $thisField contains a form fieldname, so it should always be a string at least, even if it would contain `"0"`.

Answer (score 3):

`$thisField` will always be not human2 OR not contact-sumbit (if it's one, it's not the other). You definitely meant `&&`:

```
if($thisField != "human2" && $thisField != "contact-submit")
```

Comment: @PaulHanak: Yes, `&&` returns `true` if both operands are `true`. You want it to process the field if it's "neither `human2` nor `contact-submit`", which is another way of saying "not `human2` and not `contact-submit`". So it's more like one of those "multiply two negatives and get a positive" deals.

Comment: Thanks @minitech.  I REALLLY had to break it down in my head, but I go it. hehe.  Funny how the simple things stump me sometimes.